# How can I automatically setup and configure the Windows Subsystem for Linux under Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I set up WSL on Windows 10 it wants me to manually configure it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide

That does not work well for automation. Is there a way that I can install and configure it such that it does not require manual setup?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Perhaps, this was a pre-requisite to some automation programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the MSDN documentation refers to an interactive process, there are a handful of cmdlets and commands you can execute to get you into a workable state without manual intervention.

The following information assumes you are running from a modern instance of PowerShell, and will be executing in that environment as an Administrator.

---

> [Enable Developer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development). This provides you the option and availability to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (feature).

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock"/t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"
```

Once this has been completed you can observe that in the "For developers" section of "Update & security" settings that Developer mode is now toggled ON.

[image: developer mode on]

> Install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta) feature, and suppress the reboot prompt.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature `
    -Online `
    -NoRestart `
    -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Optionally observe that within the Windows features that Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta) is now available.

[image: wsl feature now available]

Unfortunately, it does not appear possible to use the environment without a reboot. The binaries we call into are not even present in `system32` yet.

> Reboot the machine

```
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Be aware that `-Force` does not wait for programs to finish up and kill gracefully. I have placed this here to prevent scenarios where unruly processes can hang the reboot procedure.

> Extract and prep the WSL environment

```
& lxrun /install /y
```

[image: WSL extracting environment]

`&` executes a command via `cmd.exe`, as `lxrun` is not a PowerShell cmdlet but rather a executable. `lxrun /install` extracts out your new Linux filesystem, and `/y` suppresses the need to create a user or password, which leaves you with password-less `root`.

[image: using WSL environment]

---

Condensed:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock"/t REG_DWORD /f /v "AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense" /d "1"

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature `
    -Online `
    -NoRestart `
    -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

Restart-Computer -Force

# once your machine is back up... execute:

& lxrun /install /y
```

---

Additional resource material:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development
- https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1445
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer
- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-developer-mode-27008e86